# Select2 automatic select item on focus out

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to autoselect current item focused when I click outside select2 (or press TAB) and not only if I click the item to fire the event: `.on('select2:select')`

Usefull for example without using mouse and moving from an input to another only with keyboard using TAB.

In the pic for example i'd like to select the item focused also if I click in the blue-striped area (outside the select-input) or using TAB.

I don't find any documentation for select2.

fiddle to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/ishanbakshi/fyhsz9ra/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help. See my comments on the code.
Also, there are other [useful configuration](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) found on select2 documentation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#e1").select2({
  selectOnClose: true, //auto select when select2 dropdown is closed
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work. Nothing appens when I click outside

Comment: I edited the code to let you see what happens when you click outside

Comment: Mh it's not what i need... i need to autoselect an item not yet selected (so input field is empty). For example i click outside when an element is focused (background = blue) i need to insert this inside input field without clicking directly in the element

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini oh, that's easy. i just edited my answer